# Magento 2 - display html content in system.xml configuration

Tags: magento2, module, system.xml

i want to show some htmlContent in configuration. System.xml. how it could be?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: i never checked. you can share your code as wel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append html with following ways

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Some Test</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[test contet]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>Test\Module\Block\Test</frontend_model>

                </field>
```

block code

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {


    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= 'use your logice here';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @progos i will check and let you know.

Comment: worked well. (y)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add block file in as `<frontend_model>` in your xml file.

### What is frontend_model ?

we can say that, **frontend_model** specifies one type class in which you can add file path of ***block/model*** and then call ***phtml file/data*** for add custom input fields.

**system.xml :**

```
<field id="date_fields_order" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Date Fields Order</label>
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Renderer\Config\DateFieldsOrder</frontend_model>
                </field>
```

**DateFieldsOrder.php (Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Renderer\Config\DateFieldsOrder) :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Renderer\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class DateFieldsOrder extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Element HTML fragment
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        //$html = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\File')->setData($data)->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::file.phtml')->toHtml();
        $html = '<tr id="row_' . $element->getHtmlId() . '" style="display: none;"></tr>'; //You can add here your html code
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element) . $html;
    }
}
```

You can take reference : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

Hope, it's useful for you.

Comment: what if i want to call html file $html?

Comment: You mean you want to add html file path as $html?

Comment: yes exactly. instead of wrting complete html code, i want to call html file which is placed in frontend/web/template

Comment: Check my updated answer. commented $html is useful for calling html template file.

Comment: Okay sure... :)