# How can I add custom HTML to an extension config page?

Tags: magento2, html

I am trying to add an `HTML` **snippet** to my extension's config page.

I believe I need to create a block file and then reference this inside my extension's `system.xml` file using a `<frontend_model>` tag, but am unsure what to put in the block file.

If anyone knows how to do this then some basic example code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define frontend model to point to block logic

Something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259294/70343

> you can append html with following ways

```
    <field id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Some Test</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[test contet]]></comment>
                        <frontend_model>Test\Module\Block\Test</frontend_model>

                    </field>
```

> block code

```
    <?php
    namespace Test\Module\Block;

    class Test extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {


        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
            $html = $element->getElementHtml();
            $value = $element->getData('value');

            $html .= 'use your logice here';
            return $html;
        }

    }
```

Easiest solution I can find

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/165822)

Comment: I assumed linked to within stack exchange was acceptable