# Magento 2: how to give option in custom extension for new version update in configuration

Tags: magento2

I have created my custom extension. But I need to add the new version update option in my extension configuration.

How I can do? Please suggest any idea in admin configuration and in code wise.

When I update the version then how I can show in the admin configuration to update the new version with the previous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add custom html to configuration page.
Link: [Magento 2 - display html content in system.xml configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259292/magento-2-display-html-content-in-system-xml-configuration)

Second in your same block use curl to get latest version and then compare with module version and return html accordingly
Link: https://webkul.com/blog/use-curl-magento-2/

Hope this will help you.
I have never try but I have seen same thing in third party extension

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you@Nilesh.. I will try and let you know if it is useful for me